# HTML - Menu item one pixel off at 90% and 110% zoom

Tags: html, css, web

I update the website's content (not via a CMS) for the company I work for. I'm by no means an expert, but can get by with what we need. http://www.surreyilc.org.uk is the site.

I've recently seen an error in the positioning the first top bar menu item (HOME / WHO WE ARE) and can't work out why it's happening.

The menu items' positioning is one pixel above where it should be when you zoom at 90% and 110% in Chrome, Firefox and IE. All other zoom amounts don't show this error in positioning.

Could anyone please inform me of why it's doing this, and potentially, a way to fix it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the reason to test your site in differente zoom levels?

Comment: We're a charity that assists disabled people to live more independently in their own home, so we strive to be as accessible as possible, and zoom levels are something we're very wary about.

Comment: I understand, sorry! but in my opinion is tricky to guess What will be the browser behavior at different zoom levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove height and padding-top for menu items and use below styles

```
a.navitem, a.navitem:link, a.navitem:visited, a.navitem:active
{
    ...
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
}
a.navitem.double, a.navitem.double:link, a.navitem.double:visited, a.navitem.double:active
{
    ...
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at this!

Comment: Worked very well, thank you so much!  The 'active' double-line-link is taking properties from the single-line-link, so cutting out the 2nd line, but I bet it's an error in the way the site was made! This answers the question brilliantly. Thank you again!